# Windows 7 PC crashes when attempting to join Windows Server 2003 AD domain

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-7, active-directory

We have an issue when we add a Windows 7 machine to our domain.

We have a domain, running a Windows Server 2003 domain, and using XP machines, and are wanting to start using Windows 7.

However, when we try and join a Win 7 machine to the domain, shortly afterwards (minutes), the Win7 machine crashes, and on reboot, it fails to recover using any System Restores (which means nothing in the Event Log!).

This has happened on reinstalled XP machines (wiped, and installed Win7 on them) and on new Win7 machines (machines built with, and supplied with Win7 installed)

There is a group policy on the network, but the user logging in is exempt from that (admin...)

**Update**: Appears to be unrelated to UAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looks like we've resolved this.

The issue appears to be solved by :

1. Install Windows 7
2. Go to HP Site, and install drivers
3. Do Windows Update (and get 40+updates installed....)
4. THEN join the domain.

If you join the domain at any point before this, the machine will bluescreen and fail to recover..